# Intent to view a single raw contact in Android

Tags: android

Is there any way to view a raw contact via an intent (or any other way short of making my own UI for it)? I can use `ACTION_VIEW` to view a whole contact, but I need to let the user pick from a list of raw contacts. Sending the URI of the raw contact results in android.process.acore crashing.

Thanks in advance.

**To clarify:** please see the 4th comment.

Comment: have you tried `ACTION_PICK`? That should give you a list and with the result of it you can open the contact itself

Comment: I have tried it now. Unfortunately that gives an `ActivityNotFoundException`, so you can't pick from raw contacts. Besides, it is not the entire list of raw contacts I want to pick from. In fact it is only the raw contacts within a contact that have a specific MIME type set. I can display these fine. I just need to be able to view them. Otherwise, the user will not know which one they want, because they will likely have similar names.

Comment: Maybe I haven't understood your question correctly, but why can't you make your own activity and add the corresponding intent filters to either pick or view the raw contacts?

Comment: I have a subset of the raw contacts of a contact, displayed in a list by their names (which are probably similar), which I would like the user to select from. In order to get a better idea of which raw contact to pick, they may need to look at the details of each raw contact. I do not want to view the whole contact's details - just a raw contact. My activity's purpose is for selecting a raw contact.

Comment: My current workaround is to have a link to the entire contact. The user then has to remember the index of the raw contact they want, then return to the selection screen.